# How to avoid escape for Django tags in HTML

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm reading an entire page's content from database and render them in a HTML file. Here are some examples.
In database:

```
<a href="{% url 'home_view' %}></a>
```

In order to avoid escape of HTML tags, I use `{{ page.content|safe }}`
 But I couldn't render `{% url 'home_view' %}`

Answer (score 1):

You can control auto-escaping behavior using `autoescape` template tag. In your case, you can use the below snippet.

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ page.content }}{% endautoescape %}
```

You can get more information in [autoescape Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape)